# xsl:fo text-decoration="underline" line thickness

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I am trying to use the following in my code.

```
<fo:block font-weight="bold" font-size="x-large" text-decoration="underline">QUOTATION</fo:block>
```

but I want to be able to control the thickness and possibly the style of the line, I am aware I could use a

```
<fo:block font-weight="bold" font-size="x-large" border-bottom="solid 1mm">QUOTATION</fo:block>
```

but this one is being used in a table and I'm not sure how I make it specific to the text not the cell. So the text-decoration seemed more appropriate.

is there such a thing as `<fo:block>text-decoration="underline solid 1mm"</fo:block>` because the line is too thin.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using AH Formatter, then you can use `axf:text-line-width` (and other related properties).  See https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf64/ahf-ext.html#text-decoration

To make either `axf:text-line-width` or `border-bottom` apply to just the text, wrap the text in `fo:inline` and use the property on that.

Comment: Thank you, <fo:block font-weight="bold" font-size="x-large" ><fo:inline border-bottom="solid 1mm">QUOTATION</fo:inline></fo:block> worked. Now I can control the thickness of the line and it stays the length of the text